# Travis CI giving *The command "npm config set spin false" failed and exited with 127 during .*

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

I am new to Travis CI and I am trying to integrate a very simple package in nodejs.

When I run the tests locally they succeed, but when Travis is trying to run the tests, it fails with the following test:

```
... (600 lines of logs)
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/travis/.nvm/src/node-v0.4.12/build'
'install' finished successfully (0.092s)
Now using node v0.4.12
/home/travis/build.sh: line 45: npm: command not found
The command "npm config set spin false" failed and exited with 127 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

And the content of the .travis.yml file is as follows:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.4
  - 0.5
  - 0.6
```

Any idea what could be happening?

This is the repository in Travis:  https://travis-ci.org/agarcian/passwordhash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `npm` isn't getting installed in that environment.  You're targeting node `0.4`, which [isn't supported](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-node) by npm.  Note that the error for [your `0.6` build environment](https://travis-ci.org/agarcian/passwordhash/jobs/137347977) is different:

> `Error: No compatible version found: buffer-equal-constant-time@'^1.0.1'`

These are very old versions of node.

Did you maybe mean to target `4`, `5` and `6` instead of `0.4`, `0.5` and `0.6`?

Comment: Absolutely right.  I copied the file from somewhere else and didn't pay attention to the versions.   It is actually working right now with the convenience versions 5, 6.  (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs)